# devise allows anyone to lookup a user by its email address! how to prevent this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation

Devise allows user email lookups.

This is a certain privacy issue. The problem is if you ask for a new confirmation e-mail you can type in any email address you want and if its not found in the database you get a "not found" thus enabling anyone to check if a certain email is registered.

What could be a good way to fix this? I haven't posted this to the devise group but Im not sure if this is "Wanted" behavior.

Offending route : /users/confirmation

Its not an option for me to disable the confirmations module of devise. Anyone a good workaround to fix this?

Comment: did you try changing the "error-message" to something different?

Comment: Yes I thought someone would come up with that solution ( no offense ) it would still show a red box around for the error styling that would give away the problem. Would have to disable that, its not a real solution but could be a workaround if this feature is very hard to get done

Comment: you can customize all the devise controllers and implement your custom logic. i guess for you this would be https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devise has a paranoid mode that helps you to avoid user enumeration. You can get more information on Devise wiki:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Using-paranoid-mode,-avoid-user-enumeration-on-registerable

Answer (score 0):

As Devise notes in the their docs, paranoid mode doesn't avoid user enumeration on registration. If you're using `confirmable` you can fix this by showing all users a notice to check their e-mail when they attempt to register.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super do |resource|
      handle_nonunique_email if resource.errors.added?(:email, :taken)
      return if performed?
    end
  end

  private

  def handle_nonunique_email
    resource.errors.delete(:email)

    if resource.errors.empty?
      user = User.find_by_email(resource.email)
      user.send_confirmation_instructions unless user.confirmed?
      respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

I wrote more about this [here](http://vivianbrown.net/blog/rails-email-privacy.html).